# Workbench не подключается к базе

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

Поднял mysql в docker контейнере командой:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_USER=root -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -d  mysql
```

Пытаюсь присоединится через workbench но вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело оказалось в том, что workbench на данный момент не поддерживает мускуль 8й версии. С такой командой все заработает:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_USER=root -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -d  mysql:5
```